# why I am getting RelationNotFoundException in laravel?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two model such as this code :

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'country';

    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}
```

and :

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected  $table = 'city';
    protected $fillable = array("name");
}
```

now I am tring to fetch all Countries with their cities using this code:

```
$countries = Country::all();
$countries->load('App\City');
return json_encode($countries);
```

or this One :

```
Country::with("App\City")->get();
```

but I am getting this exception :

**Call to undefined relationship [App\City] on model [App\Country]**

I try "City" and "city" instead of "App\City" but steel exception remains. where is my mistake and how can I resolve this Issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. Imust to use **cities** instead of **City** or **App\City**.